# Condensing Rows with NAs in a Dataframe (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, row

So I have a dataframe

mydf

```
            Pro1    Pro2    Pro3    Pro4
Pathway1    Woot    <NA>    Yeet    Yike
Pathway2    Dang    <NA>    <NA>    Yike
Pathway3    Blah    Try     <NA>    Lost
```

And I wan't to compress the NA's so it looks like this

revisedmydf

```
            Pro1    Pro2    Pro3    Pro4
Pathway1    Woot    Yeet    Yike
Pathway2    Dang    Yike
Pathway3    Blah    Try     Lost
```

Basically, the NA's are deleted and then the information in the column next to it is pulled into it's space.  I have no idea how to approach this and am not sure if I titled this question correctly or am using the correct terminology.  So, if this is a duplicate question out there, I apologize.
Best!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `apply` to loop over the rows, concatenate the elements of row that are non-NA along with replicated blanks (`""`) based on the number of 'NA' elements (It may be better to have NA instead of `""` - In that case `c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])`)

```
mydf[] <- t(apply(mydf, 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], rep("", sum(is.na(x))))))
mydf
#         Pro1 Pro2 Pro3 Pro4
#Pathway1 Woot Yeet Yike     
#Pathway2 Dang Yike          
#Pathway3 Blah  Try Lost
```

---

Or use `order`

```
mydf[] <- t(apply(mydf, 1, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))]))
```

Comment: For some reason when I run that code, it is not giving me the same output it gives you

Comment: @TaylorMaurer  Could you please check the `str` of your dataset.  Do you have `NA` or `"NA"`.  What is the output of `is.na(mydf)` in your example data before the transform

Comment: It was "NA". Once I converted it to NA it worked.  Thanks!